# Quasi-static-detector operation principle

Tags: discrete-signals, lowpass-filter, digital-filters, highpass-filter

Im currently working on a project to get navigation information of a robot from Data-Fusion through different IMUs.

First step is to make a calibration and I picked a method where I need to detect several "quasi-static-states" for the calibration process of a 9 DOF IMU (see Paper "Automatic Calibration for Inertial Measurement Unit").

*Quasi-Static Motion:*
Motion which refers to very slow motions / rotations (about ten seconds per revolution) by hand that are closed to the equilibrium state.

The accelerometer calibration requires static (in rest) measurements and the magnetometer calibration requires quasi-static motion.

**Quasi-Static-States:** The aggregate of detected static states and quasi-static motions are the quasi-static-states.

To detect theses states the paper presents 3 detectors for the sensor types accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope using lowpass- (LPF), highpass-filter (HPF) and an rectification (RECT) operator.
The detector of the accelerometer is given with
$$
    s_a = ||LPF(RECT(HPF(a_{raw})))||_2
$$
and for quasi static state detection of acc I modified the overall equation to

$$
    s=1/(1+s_a)
$$
for understanding reasons.

Trying this with the rectification operator $rect(x) = |x|$ and the filters

```
lowpass_filter_acc = scipy.signal.butter(5, Wn=5, btype="lowpass", output="sos", fs=100.0)
highpass_filter_acc = scipy.signal.butter(5, Wn=49, btype="highpass", output="sos", fs = 100.0)
```

and different cutoff frequencies my "best" quasi-static-state-detection was this
with my expectation in the bottom marked in red.
[image]

I think I dont understand the concept to filter high frequency first and filter low frequency second. My guess is that my cutoff and or my rectification operator is designed wrong because of it.
I ask for the explanation of the approach and some adjustments to get the signal processing right to get the right timestamps of quasi-static-states.

THX

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to explain what you mean by "quasi-static states".  I think that means that you're trying to determine whether the IMU is at rest, but I don't want to assume that.

Answer (score 0):

- The high pass filter works like a derivative, it will detect movement.
- The rectifier will make it work the same way for changes in both directions.
- The low pass filter works like an integrator.

If we take each analogous we would write as a formula

$$ \int \left| \partial r(t) / \partial t \right| dt $$

That calculates the length of the curve `r(t)`

To make it more invariant to direction you could replace the rectifier by a vector norm.

The fact that the LPF is not a perfect integrator makes it to return to zero if the excitation stops. In other words you go to quasi-static state when the LPF output is close to zero.